# Warning when compiling a C++/CLI DLL

Tags: c#, google-api, c++-cli, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am developing a C++/CLI targeting .NET 4.0 that references my C# project with the Google Calendar API. 
The problem is, when I try to compile the C++ .DLL, it gives me the following warning:

> The primary reference "GoogleCalendar.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "GoogleCalendar.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

I couldn't find any solutions to this problem, my app.config is already trying to redirect the System.Net.Http:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Another problem (don't know if related or not), when I compile my C++ project that references the C#:

> warning : Project must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl,
>   version=1.1.10. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317570.

But won't let me install because it's not native C#.

Answer (score 0):

The google .net client library supports [.net framework 4.5+](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client)

[image]

While we try to support 4.0 not everything is going to work and I haven't tried it in quite sometime.   I recommend trying to go back to an older version of the library something around 1.12 I think should support 4.0

start here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/1.12.0.472 and work your way up see if you can find the version where it stops working.

Comment: I tried to go back until version 1.9.2.1480 and the warning still occurs. Another problem (don't know if related or not) is that when I compile my C++ project that references the C#, it gives me the warning:                                                   
Project must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl, version=1.1.10. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317570. But won't let me install because it's not native C#.

Comment: You need to have the the corect version of nuget to install it i think.   TBH I didnt know you could use C# packages in C++.

Comment: I'm not completely sure that I should install the BCL packages in my C++ project, but the warning guides me to. The problem of not letting me install the Microsoft.Bcl seems like something to do with not being a .NET project, the error says: Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.